# Getting headphone to work on 2011 Imac 27"

Tags: mac

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Imac and it works flawlessly apart from the fact that I don't get sound from my headphone jack.

The sounds works fine on the speaker.

Does anyone have any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it doesn't work for me, but it does work for some people:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Append `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122` to the file
3. Reboot